# Jackson deserialization of nested objects of which one references the other. UnresolvedForwardReference

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "node" : {
    "number" : 5,
    "x" : 2000.0,
    "y" : 1500.0
  },
  "force" : {
    "number" : 1,
    "value" : -20.0,
    "angle" : 90.0,
    "node" : 5
  }
}
```

Into the following object:

```
public class NodeWithForce {

    private Node node;
    private Force force;

    public NodeWithForce(){}

    public NodeWithForce(Node node, Force force) {
        this.node = node;
        this.force = force;
    }

    //getters and setters for Node and Force, Equals and Hashcode
}
```

Node class:

```
public class Node {

    private long number;
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Node() {}

    public Node(long number, double x, double y) {
        this.number = number;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    //getters and setters for number, x and y, equals and hashcode
    }
}
```

Force class:

```
public class Force {

    private long number;
    private double value;
    private double angle;

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "number")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    private Node node;

    public Force() {}

    public Force(long number, double value, double angle, Node node) {
        this.number = number;
        this.value = value;
        this.angle = angle;
        this.node = node;
    }

    //getters and setters for number, value, angle and node. Equals and Hashcode.
}
```

So Node is part of the wrapper object NodeWithForce and also of one of the wrappers children: Force. The actual data structure is more complex than this, but I tried reducing the complexity and keeping only the part that matters for this question here on SO.

Then when I run this:

```
public NodeWithForce getNodeWithForce() throws Exception {
    Node node = new Node(5, 2000, 1500);
    Force force = new Force(1, -20, 90, node);
    NodeWithForce nwf = new NodeWithForce(node,force);
    NodeWithForce nwf2 = null;
    ObjectMapper om = context.getBean(ObjectMapper.class);
    om.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    String jsonRepresentation = null;
    jsonRepresentation = om.writeValueAsString(nwf);
    System.out.println(jsonRepresentation);
    nwf2 = om.readValue(jsonRepresentation, NodeWithForce.class);
    System.out.println("equal: " + nwf.equals(nwf2));
    return nwf2;
}
```

It gives me the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference: Unresolved forward references for: 
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "node" : {
    "number" : 5,
    "x" : 2000.0,
    "y" : 1500.0
  },
  "force" : {
    "number" : 1,
    "value" : -20.0,
    "angle" : 90.0,
    "node" : 5
  }
}"; line: 13, column: 1]Object id [5] (for `com.company.calculationmanager.pojos.Node`) at [Source: (String)"{
  "node" : {
    "number" : 5,
    "x" : 2000.0,
    "y" : 1500.0
  },
  "force" : {
    "number" : 1,
    "value" : -20.0,
    "angle" : 90.0,
    "node" : 5
  }
}"; line: 11, column: 15].
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.checkUnresolvedObjectId(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:165) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4015) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
```

Serialization works because it prints the object as json to the console, but deserialization does not, even though I added the JsonIdentityInfo annotation.

Am I missing some annotations here? I think writing a separate deserializer is a bit too much for this simple piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation on the `Node` class, not the field in `Force`:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "number")
public static class Node { //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new setter method setNode in the NodeWithForce class that accept int:

```
    private void setNode(int number) {
        setNode(new Node(number));
    }
```